# How can I tell if an object is a "date-y" type of object in Ruby (convertable to a unix timestamp)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, unix, datetime

Specifically, if an object can be converted to a unix timestamp, I'd like to convert it to a unix timestamp. This is so I can override the standard Date / Time JSON format ruby uses to convert it to a unix timestamp for an API (since we don't want to parse strings phone side). And, I kinda wanted to do this once so I can use it in any of our objects that use dates / times (by modifying results from as_json).

Seems like I currently have to deal with Date, Time, DateTime (handled by Date if type checking), and ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone (from Rails). But, didn't want to have to check for all of those.

Any better way?

FYI, I tried checking for respond_to?(:to_datetime) which is no good since String responds to that. And respond_to?(:year) which is no good since FixedNum responds to that. :-P

Comment: I guess really I could just check for kind_of?(Date) and kind_of?(Time)...just noticed ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone derives from Time. Eh, will wait to see if anyone else has a better suggestion before answering it though. :)

Comment: Calling to_i on a date/time in ruby will return the unix timestamp

Comment: Yeah, but you can call to_i on all sorts of objects that are not dates. I only want to convert to a timestamp for a date type of object. In most languages, I'd check if it implemented some kinda date interface (or responds to a selector that is specifically for getting a timestamp).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using `respond_to?`

why don't you do:

```
def date_or_time?(obj)
  obj.kind_of?(Date) || obj.kind_of?(Time)
end

[19] pry(main)> a = Date.new
=> #<Date: -4712-01-01 ((0j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
[20] pry(main)> date_or_time? a
=> true
[21] pry(main)> b = DateTime.new
=> #<DateTime: -4712-01-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((0j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
[22] pry(main)> date_or_time? b
=> true
[23] pry(main)> c = Time.new
=> 2013-12-06 10:44:57 -0600
[24] pry(main)> date_or_time? c
=> true
```

Comment: see his comment above

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what I'm gonna go with. Guess any date-y kind of object will likely derive from Date or Time anyway. I'll accept your answer since I hadn't put in my own. :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could still use `respond_to?` with `:iso8601`. I believe only 'date-y' types will respond to that (Date, Time, DateTime).